# May Megillat Esther be read from a seated position?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther

Is there any problem with reading Megillat Esther (or, for that matter, reading from a sefer torah) while sitting?  Does this still fulfill the mitzvah?  I have only ever seen it done standing, but have no idea whether that is because it's a requirement to do so, or whether it is merely a matter of style.  What if, for example, the reader has a medical condition that makes it difficult for him to remain standing for an extended period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Mishna in Megilla 21a it seems that one can lechatchila read in any position he likes (standing or sitting). However, see the Tur who brings those who say it is not lechatchila to sit. The Shulchan Aruch writes that one who reads for the tzibur should stand . The Mishna Brurah writes that one should stand ,and also notes that leaning may be fine lechatichla (see his Biur Halacha on this) . The Be'er Heitv notes that for the brachos one should stand. It should be noted that the Kaf Hachaim concludes that one can sit lechatchila.

On a side note reading from the Torah in a sitting position is problematic and one would need to reread the Torah while standing ,see Ateres Zekeinim.

Text of Mishna:

הַקּוֹרֵא אֶת הַמְּגִילָּה עוֹמֵד וְיוֹשֵׁב קְרָאָהּ אֶחָד קְרָאוּהָ שְׁנַיִם יָצְאוּ מָקוֹם שֶׁנָּהֲגוּ לְבָרֵךְ יְבָרֵךְ וְשֶׁלֹּא לְבָרֵךְ לֹא יְבָרֵךְ

Text of Tur 690:

הקורא המגילה עומד או יושב יצא משמע בדיעבד אבל לכתחלה לא יקרא יושב ובירושלמי קאמר דאפילו לכתחלה והרמב"ם ז"ל כתב אבל לא יקרא לכתחלה יושב בצבור מפני כבוד הצבור

Text of Shulchan Aruch 690:1

דיני קריאת המגילה. ובו יח סעיפים:
קורא אדם את המגילה בין עומד בין יושב אבל לא יקרא בצבור יושב לכתחלה מפני כבוד הצבור: הגה ואסור לחזן לקרוא את המגילה עד שאומרים לו קרא [מרדכי פ' הקורא]:

Text of Kaf Hachaim:

א) [סעיף א'] קורא אדם את המגילה בין עומד בין יושב. משמע אפי' לכתחלה יכול לקרות יושב וכמ"ש הטור בשם הירושלמי. וכ"כ המ"מ וכ"פ הר"ן וכן עיקר. ב"ח:

Text of Ateres Zekeinim:

יושב. מה שאין כן בתור' דמעומד דוקא אבל יושב אפי' דעבד לא וצריך לחזור ולקרות מעומד ע"ל סי' קס"א וסימן על ז' דברים שמברכין מעומד עצת ה' לעולם תעמוד ר"ת עוז ר"ל תפילין נקראים עוז. ציצית תורה תקיעה לבנ' עומר לולב מילה (בשם העיטור):

Comment: The *Bei'ur Halacha* ([690:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6#%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%90)) cites the *Mateh Y'huda* that the reader may lean onto something for support during the reading, and the Chafetz Chaim indicates that a person can certainly rely on this if necessary (despite the otherwise prevalent custom to be stringent not to read seated): "ואף דבודאי אין לזוז מזה אחרי שהוא מנהג של כלל ישראל מ"מ דיינו אם נחמיר בזה בישיבה ממש ולא בסמיכה כנלענ"ד".